# asp.net c# generate page event handler automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

asp.net VS 4.0
Is there a way to generate page event handler like

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e){}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

automatically in c# editor? ( it is possible in VB using top of page dropdown list)

Or do I have to retype them manually for every page.

Comment: you could use the events portion of the properties pane.

Comment: wat's wrong with simple copy and paste? also, u can create a code snippet about it

Comment: Daniel: " events portion of the properties pane." I cannot find this, I switch to design mode and it is not there (VS 2013). in VS2008 there use to be a lightning icon.

Comment: snippet is the way to go, I just don't get why it is there in the VB editor and not in the C# Editor.